# How to use async/await syntax with the debunce function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, async-await, debouncing

Trying to create an react autocomplete component and use `debounce` function to reduce frequent api call. The code is following:

```js
const { useState, useMemo } = React;

function debounce(fn, delay) {
  let timeoutId;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => fn.apply(this, ...args), delay);
  }
}

const getApi = (terms) => `https://www.reddit.com/search.json?q=${terms}`;
const Search = () => {
  const DELAY = 500;
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = useMemo(debounce(async(evt) => {
    const res = await fetch(getApi(evt.target.value));
    const {data} = await res.json();
    setList(data.children.map(d => d.data.title));
  }, DELAY), []);

  return (
    <div>
      <form className="bg-gray-200 p-5">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="text"
          placeholder="search users..."
          value={text}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setText(e.target.value);
            fetchData(e);
            }
          }
          className="bg-white p-2 w-3/4 outline-none"
        />
      </form>
      <ul>
        {list.map(title => <li>{title}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Search />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

The api call has not been made after I test it from console. Any idea where goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of `useMemo` is

```
const memoizedValue = useMemo(functionThatCreatesMemoizedValue, [dependencies]);
```

The first argument passed to it is executed immediately. But you have

```
const fetchData = useMemo(debounce(......), []);
```

`debounce` returns a debounced function; that debounced function is then called immediately by `useMemo`, and the return value is put into `fetchData`.

What you need to do is have a function that *returns the debounced function*.

```
const fetchData = useMemo(() => debounce(......), []);
```

```js
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  let timeoutId;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => fn.apply(this, ...args), delay);
  }
}

const Search = () => {
  const DELAY = 500;
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");
  const [list, setList] = React.useState([]);

  const fetchData = React.useMemo(() => debounce((evt) => {
    console.log('api call');
  }, DELAY), []);
  return (
    <div>
      <form className="bg-gray-200 p-5">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="text"
          placeholder="search users..."
          value={text}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setText(e.target.value);
            fetchData(e);
            }
          }
          className="bg-white p-2 w-3/4 outline-none"
        />
      </form>
      <ul>
        {list.map(title => <li>{title}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<Search />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

For a memoized value that's a callback, you can also consider using `useCallback` instead, which works nearly identically but is arguably a bit more semantically appropriate.

```
const fetchData = useCallback(debounce((evt) => {
    console.log('api call');
}, DELAY), []);
```

```js
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  let timeoutId;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => fn.apply(this, ...args), delay);
  }
}

const Search = () => {
  const DELAY = 500;
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");
  const [list, setList] = React.useState([]);

  const fetchData = React.useCallback(debounce((evt) => {
    console.log('api call');
  }, DELAY), []);
  return (
    <div>
      <form className="bg-gray-200 p-5">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="text"
          placeholder="search users..."
          value={text}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setText(e.target.value);
            fetchData(e);
            }
          }
          className="bg-white p-2 w-3/4 outline-none"
        />
      </form>
      <ul>
        {list.map(title => <li>{title}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<Search />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```